# SQL query to get Map Id on passing Id value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
Id  InvID   InvDate                     OriginalInvID   FilterDesc
1   1       2017-03-01 00:00:00.000     0               First Inv Created
2   2       2017-03-06 00:00:00.000     1               Link ID
3   3       2017-03-01 00:00:00.000     0               First Inv Created
4   4       2017-03-03 00:00:00.000     3               Link ID
5   5       2017-03-06 00:00:00.000     4               Second Inv Created on top of MapID
6   6       2017-03-01 00:00:00.000     0               First Inv Created
7   7       2017-03-03 00:00:00.000     6               Link ID
8   8       2017-03-05 00:00:00.000     7               Second In Created on top of Map Id
9   9       2017-03-06 00:00:00.000     8               Second Inv Created on top of Map Id
```

Hi, in above table I have to pass `invId` and I need result with map `Id` who is in `OriginalInvID` column.

For example:

- If I pass 1 then I get 1 & 2 `invId`
- If i pass 4 then I get 3,4,5
- If i pass 8 then I get 6,7,8,9 like this way

Comment: you need sql query? Or linq query? Or what?

Comment: this clearly is tagged wrong this is no jquery i removed it already

Answer (score 1):

If I understood what you want, I think you wanted a query like this:

```
declare @InvId int = 8;
with cte(Id, InvID, InvDate, OriginalInvID) as (
    select * 
    from yourTable
    where OriginalInvID = @InvId 
    union all
    select t.*
    from yourTable t join cte on t.InvId = cte.OriginalInvID
)
select *
from cte
order by Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop to fetch father and children nodes storing them in temp tables:

```
declare @myInvId int
declare @father_counter int
declare @children_counter int
declare @temp table (Id int,  InvID int,   InvDate datetime, OriginalInvID  int, FilterDesc nvarchar(100))
declare @fathers table(id int, status int)
declare @children table(id int, status int)

insert into @temp
          select 1, 1, '2017-03-01 00:00:00.000', 0, 'First Inv Created'
union all select 2, 2, '2017-03-06 00:00:00.000', 1, 'Link ID'
union all select 3, 3, '2017-03-01 00:00:00.000', 0, 'First Inv Created'
union all select 4, 4, '2017-03-03 00:00:00.000', 3, 'Link ID'
union all select 5, 5, '2017-03-06 00:00:00.000', 4, 'Second Inv Created on top of MapID'
union all select 6, 6, '2017-03-01 00:00:00.000', 0, 'First Inv Created'
union all select 7, 7, '2017-03-03 00:00:00.000', 6, 'Link ID'
union all select 8, 8, '2017-03-05 00:00:00.000', 7, 'Second In Created on top of Map Id'
union all select 9, 9, '2017-03-06 00:00:00.000', 8, 'Second Inv Created on top of Map Id'

--set input parameter
set @myInvId = 8

--init counters
set @father_counter = 1
set @children_counter = 1

--insert starting node
insert into @fathers  select InvID,0 from @temp where OriginalInvID = @myInvId
insert into @children select OriginalInvID,0 from @temp where InvID = @myInvId

--loop on table
while (@father_counter + @children_counter) > 0
    begin
        --fetch father nodes
        insert into @fathers  select InvID, 1 from @temp where OriginalInvID in (select id from @fathers where status=0)
        --update fathers' status
        update @fathers set status = 2 where status = 0
        update @fathers set status = 0 where status = 1

        --fetch children nodes
        insert into @children  select OriginalInvID, 1 from @temp where InvID in (select id from @children where status=0)
        --update children's status
        update @children set status = 2 where status = 0
        update @children set status = 0 where status = 1

        --update counters
        select @father_counter = count(*) from @fathers where status = 0
        select @children_counter = count(*) from @children where status = 0
    end

select @myInvId
union
select id from  @fathers 
union
select c.id from @children c inner join @temp t on c.id = t.InvID
```